# How to setup a fake SMTP server to catch all mails?

Tags: smtp, debugging

I'm looking for an smtp service that essentially obeys the RFC, except rather than sending mail it simply logs to a file

```
[date] sent mail to <address>
```

Or whatever. I can bash this together with the bare minimum of functionality I need in python in about half an hour I reckon but if there's an existing project that works better I'd rather use that.

The reason for needing it is debugging an app that keeps sending 7* the amount of mail it's supposed to.

EDIT: And already asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006650/dummy-smtp-server-for-testing-apps-that-send-email

Comment: Yes, this question was answered on stackoverflow, but I didn't see the python based answer over there.

Comment: This is also answered at stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48653699/sandbox-catch-catchall-mails-sent-from-test-environment

Comment: https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If you have python lying around this will write the SMTP conversation to stdout.

```
sudo python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:25
```

http://docs.python.org/library/smtpd.html#debuggingserver-objects

Comment: I take it back, it does support HTML emails.

Comment: still the best way to debug!

Comment: No support for *starttls* :(

Comment: @AttRigh [the smtplib has TLS implemented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.starttls) but using that isn't going to be as simple as this.  Post the question; maybe someone has a script already?

Answer (score 13):

You should have a look at `smtp-sink` which is a part of Postfix. You don't have to run Postfix to make it work. Just install it to have the executable. Everything you need can be configured via command line parameters:

http://www.postfix.org/smtp-sink.1.html

Comment: Thanks mailq. This is more or less exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 10):

There is also a ruby gem called [mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me).

You can read the emails directly in your browser through the integrated web interface, there's  a screenshot from their homepage below.

[image: Mailcatcher interface]

Comment: We currently use mailcatcher, crashes too much.

Answer (score 7):

We use http://mailtrap.io web service in developement and staging environment.
It is platform-independent and doesn't require you to run your own SMTP.

It offers:

- All emails in one place
- Shared access for dev team to the inbox
- Developer tools to analyze emails
- Flexible configuration

Comment: This is great and much more robust than what I was doing! Thanks.

Comment: I like that they offer a generous free plan (for now).

Comment: It doesn't work in Russia due to "digital racism", as I call it

Answer (score 4):

[smtp4dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) has worked well for me. (Windows only)

Comment: I just installed and used this awesome little tool. Perfect for my needs (no java and a nice UI)

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:** This is a late answer, but I genuinely believe it will help out future viewers. Also note that I worked on this product.

[We built Mailosaur](https://mailosaur.com) in order to solve this exact problem. We've since built it out to add test email addresses as well as SMTP.

Answer (score 2):

http://quintanasoft.com/dumbster/

This looks like a it'll probably do the job, for anyone else who stumbles upon this.

Comment: Too bad it requires a javavm. Plus someone has forked and worked on it more recently... https://github.com/rjo1970/dumbster

Comment: Cheers John. Java based was enough to put me off in the end, I wound up just writing something myself.

Answer (score 2):

FakeSMTP https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/ is cross-platform and open-source.

Answer (score 1):

I just fork up just about any smtp service then send the result to a bit bucket!

Comment: I'm talking about bulk emails though, and with live customer data involved. I need to be positive that I'm not going to flood the intertrons with mail.

Comment: I wound up extending python's smtpd.SMTPServer class, I'll release the project publically in a week or so when I'm happy with it (I'm bundling it with an httpd test suite I wrote a while back). I've tentatively named the suite sdb.

Comment: @Richo: there are lots of ways to stop a SMTP server from sending emails - most allow you turn off outgoing connections or reroute all messages, or you can block outgoing connections to port 25....nobody would bother writing a dummy mailserver whwn its trivial to configure a real one to behave in this way.

Comment: @symcbean: those are all valid points. Personally I find it easier to stop my usual mail service, start my debugging service, do my debugging and then fire up the live environment again.
Kludges like dumping all port 25 traffic then prevents anything else from sending mail. Thanks for the help though,

Comment: none of this makes sense, all smtp gateways will give you this exact functionality without losing any of the outbound live emails!

Comment: Tony: The point is not to send outbound emails..

Comment: duh I know that, your request is now making more sense its the fact that you want one persons (an automated process) email to be logged but not sent correct? And all other email to flow normally, correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. I don't need to run it on a production server, so running something on port 25 that dumps all mail is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fake SMTP servers come in two flavours: those you install locally, and those you access as a web service ("SaaS"). Here is an overview of the latter:

- **[WPOven Free SMTP Server for Testing](https://www.wpoven.com/tools/free-smtp-server-for-testing).** Different from many local and online fake SMTP servers, this one includes a fake SMTP authentication mechanism. It accepts any username / password combination, so it is not requiring your application to be able to send e-mails without authentication. Free.
- **[SMTP Bucket](https://www.smtpbucket.com/).** Functionality just as with the WPOven service, plus API interface, minus the dummy authentication mechanism. Free, with a donation option.
- **[Mailspons](https://mailspons.com/).** Commercial, with a generous free plan with 750 e-mails per month.
- **[Mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/).** Commercial, with a limited free plan with 100 e-mails per month.
- **[Mailosaur](https://mailosaur.com/).** Commercial, with a free trial but no free plan.